# software installation of a file having .rpm extention

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, fedora

I have a .rpm extension file which is for a GUI to an LTE base station. I used alien to convert it to .deb. Then i installed it by dpkg. The problem is, for some reason the file after unpacking disappears. It should create a desktop icon which is missing. It says the software is installed but its not. The extracted directory is missing also an executable file which in this case should be .bin.

Any thoughts on this one?

Arif

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Substance Designer, I ended up adding the --scripts argument to the alien statement and the resulting deb package ran without a hitch. The full command would be something like...

```
sudo alien --scripts -d PackageNameHere.rpm
```

The logs from DPKG may also hold some clues. If that doesn't work, you could try having Alien install it by adding a -i to the command.